# Android: Passing value from view class to another activity back and forth

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have manage to switch to new activity from my view class. It initiate a start of new activity though a dialog and passing the name of a particular circle to the new activity. However, i could not successfully pass the name to the new activity and displays in a textview located in the new activity. The textview on the new activity remains null. Please advice on this issue. Thank you.

Ontouchevent code from my view class:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();


            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {


                    if (circles.get(i).contains(x, y)) {
                        circleID = i;

        Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(
                                            getContext());
                                    final EditText text = new EditText(getContext());

                                    builder.setTitle("Adding colors to circles").setMessage(
                                            "Proceed to Enter color");
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di,
                                                        int i) {

                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                                            getContext(),
                                                            colorActivity.class);

                                                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                                     intent.putExtra("circlename", circleNameList.get(circleID));
                                                }

                                            });
                                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di,
                                                        int i) {
                                                }

                                            });

                                    builder.create().show();
                                }
                            }, 3000);
break;

}
```

In the new activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_ecolor);


        circlenametextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.circlenametextview);


        String circlename = super.getIntent().getStringExtra("circlename");
          circlenametextview.setText(circlename);
        }
```

Comment: you need to add the extras before starting the activity i.e., you need to add putextra line before  getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: @Raghunandan I am sorry i have made changes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),colorActivity.class);
  getContext().startActivity(intent); // you start activity
  intent.putExtra("circlename", circleNameList.get(circleID)); // then you have putExtra
```

to

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),colorActivity.class); 
  intent.putExtra("circlename", circleNameList.get(circleID)); //putExtra first
  getContext().startActivity(intent); // then startactivity
```

Comment: In my new activity, users are allowed to enter the color for the particular color they selected. How would this works if i need to pass back the color back to the view class again?

Comment: you need to use `startActivityForResult` and get the data back  in previous activity using intent and pass the same to the view class

Comment: do you have any references with regards to that?

Comment: @user3306996 there are lots of similar examples are stackoverflow. google search it